# How to do a union across multiple instances of Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two Sql Servers (two distinct databases, (i.e. two machines)) with the same structure. Is there a way to do a SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TableOnServerA Union SELECT * FROM TableOnServerB)?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just set them up as [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) and then fully qualify the names in the form of `LinkName.DatabaseName.SchemaName(dbo).TableName`

Comment: But be wary--setting up linked server definitions can get pretty tricky.

Comment: Yes, it works with SQL Server 2005, and in my experience it's been pretty straight-forward.  Just a matter of getting the permissions right on the account you use and (usually) remembering to set up the link in both directions.

Comment: Can you do that without setting up a linked server?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM serverA.database.owner.TableName
Union 
SELECT * FROM serverB.database.owner.Tablename
```

assuming that they are setup as linked server, use books online and go to "linked"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Linked Server or use OPENROWSET to connect to other SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a query relating two different machines adding one machine via the [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) stored procedure. You run it in the database server instance where you will want to execute the query (or on both if you want to execute the query in any server), like this

```
use master
go
exec sp_addlinkedserver 
@server='AnotherServer',
@provider='SQL Server'
```

The you can run

select * from AnotherServer.database.dbo.table t1 
   join database.dbo.table t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally if they are on two different servers and you are sure the data is not duplicated use union all, it will be much faster. Also never use select *,specify the field names. Other wise it will break if someone adds a column to A but not to B (or rearranges teh  columns in B but not A) I would also add a column indicating which of the two servers the data came from, especially if they might have the same id number but attached to different data (which can happen if you are using autogenerated ids). This can save no end of trouble.